# System.OutOfMemoryException when i m uploading more than 20MB Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream

I am Uploading Image more than 20 MB, 2 or 3 times that image uploaded properly, but after performing more than 5-6 uploads it gives an error, and after that it works proper for less than 1MB images but not allow to save more than 1MB images

Perorming below opration,

1. Convert image in `base64String`
2. Convert `base64string` into `byte`;

   `byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Sting);`

From that `imagebytes` I am trying to crop that images according to height & width  and XY coordinates using `Grapics.DrawImage()`

but it gives me an error;

> Out of memory.
>   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
>   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
    {               
         //Operations
    }
}
```

But it Gives an Error at

`System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)`

Comment: Converting the image to a base 64 string will increase the memory requirements significantly. a 20MB might need 60-80MB or more. No wonder you are having problems. You need to rethink the way you are doing this

Comment: "i) Convert image in base64String" - in what form do you have the image here? Is all that conversion really necessary?

Comment: You are disposing (`using`) properly, still GDI+ leaks could cause the described behavior that it works for the first few big ones and then no longer. Of course it is correct that the base64 encoding bloats the operation unnecessarily, but it should be repeatable. Use a memory profiler.

Comment: yes  Convert image in base64String :  yes here is image and  I disposed all using variable properly.